# Is it possible to remove submodule from Gitlab project using Gitlab Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab

Help me, please.
I have local Giltab installation with many(~600) small test projects.
Some of them are old, and not needed any more. I can delete all of it using Gitlab Rails, but there is a problem - few usable projects have submodule links to removable projects.

Is the way to remove that links using Gitlab Rails?
Or that impossible?

In target solution it will be a script in crontab, to remove oldest projects.

Gitlab version is 15.4

I read documentation, but didn't find how it can be made.
All articles I found recommend only one way - clone repo and remove submodule with git commands.